# Not able to display messages in HTML page in chat app using flask-socketio

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I am making a flask chat application using flask-socketio. When I click the send button no messages are displayed on the screen. I have referenced the flask-socketio documentation for setting everything up. Can someone please help me here.
mainapp.py snippet

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'replace later'

# Initialise Flask-Socketio
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/chat", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chat():
    return render_template('chat.html')

@socketio.on('message')
def message(data):
    #print(f"\n{data}\n")
    send(data)
```

chat.html snippet

```
<div id="display-message-section">
</div>
<!-- Input area -->
<div id="input-area">
    <input type="text" id="user_message" placeholder="Type here..." autocomplete="off">
    <button type="button" id="send_message">SEND</button>
</div>
<!-- SocketIO JS -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Custom SocketIO JS -->
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/socketio.js') }}"></script>
```

socketio.js (which is in static/scripts) snippet

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    socket.on('connect', () => {
        socket.send("I am connected");
    });

    socket.on('message', data =>{
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        const br = document.createElement('br');
        p.innerHTML = data;
        document.querySelector('#display-message-section').append(p);
    });

    document.querySelector('#send_message').onclick = ()=>{
        socket.send(document.querySelector('#user_message').value);
    }
})
```

What the output looks like - [Link to image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3VJL.png)

What is should look like - [Link to image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Xgj.png)

Comment: Please enable Socket.IO logs on the server and include them in your question. Also look in the browser's network tab for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Tried clearing the cookies and cache and everything is working fine right now.